# Tou fazendo webscraping com python e não consigo quebrar um loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estou automatizando a pesquisa por notebooks gamer na amazon, que além de pegar a primeira página ele pega as próximas, mas ele chega num ponto que não para de tentar pegar mais paginas e **nunca** sai do loop e eu já tentei fazer verificações, se não existe mais páginas para seguir, que quando for verdadeiro torna a variável continuar como false, etc. Segue o código abaixo

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_index = 1
index = 0
continuar = True
link = 'https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=acer+nitro+5&rh=n%3A16364755011&s=price-asc-rank&dc&__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&qid=1625947439&rnid=18726358011&ref=sr_nr_n_1'

site = requests.get(f'{link}&page={page_index}')

print("Notebooks gamer Acer nitro 5:\n\n")

#a-pagination

while continuar:
    site_bs4 = BeautifulSoup(site.text, 'html.parser')

    items = site_bs4.findAll('div', class_="s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-latency-cf-section {{ "
                                           "borderCssClass }}")

    div_paginas = site_bs4.find('div', class_='a-text-center')
    paginacao = div_paginas.find_all('li', class_='a-last')
    if (paginacao):
        for pagina in paginacao:
            global paginas
            paginas = pagina.find('a')

        if(index == len(items)):
                if(paginas):
                    site = requests.get(f'https://www.amazon.com.br/{paginas["href"]}')

    for item in items:
        index += 1
        print(index)
        titulo = item.find('span', class_ = 'a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal')
        url = item.find('a', class_='a-link-normal a-text-normal')
        preco = item.find('span', class_='a-price-whole')

        #preco = items.find('a', class_='a-size-base a-link-normal a-text-normal')

        if(preco):
            print(f'Produto: {titulo.text}')
            print(f'https://www.amazon.com.br/{url["href"]}')
            print(f'Preço: R${preco.text.replace(",", "")}')
        else:
            print(f'Produto não disponível: {titulo.text}...\nDa url: https://www.amazon.com.br/{url["href"]}')
        print("\n")

print('\nLista acabada!')
```

Espero que possam me ajudar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro é mais simples do que parece: Você não colocou uma condição onde a variável `continuar`  vira `False`, assim o código fica repetindo infinitamente.

Para solucionar adicionei a linha `continuar = False` após a execução de todos os seus loops internos.

Também havia alguns errinhos (como a declaração de `global paginas` dentro de um `for` com que faria com que fosse redefinida a cada loop), probleminhas de identação fora do padrão Python, etc.

No final das contas o seguinte código funcionou certinho:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_index = 1
index = 0
continuar = True
link = 'https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=acer+nitro+5&rh=n%3A16364755011&s=price-asc-rank&dc&__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&qid=1625947439&rnid=18726358011&ref=sr_nr_n_1'

site = requests.get(f'{link}&page={page_index}')

print("Notebooks gamer Acer nitro 5:\n\n")

#a-pagination

while continuar:
    site_bs4 = BeautifulSoup(site.text, 'html.parser')

    items = site_bs4.findAll('div', class_="s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-latency-cf-section {{ "
                                           "borderCssClass }}")

    div_paginas = site_bs4.find('div', class_='a-text-center')
    paginacao = div_paginas.find_all('li', class_='a-last')
    if (paginacao):
        global paginas
        for pagina in paginacao:
            paginas = pagina.find('a')

        if(index == len(items)):
                if(paginas):
                    site = requests.get(f'https://www.amazon.com.br/{paginas["href"]}')

    for item in items:
        index += 1
        print(index)
        titulo = item.find('span', class_ = 'a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal')
        url = item.find('a', class_='a-link-normal a-text-normal')
        preco = item.find('span', class_='a-price-whole')

        #preco = items.find('a', class_='a-size-base a-link-normal a-text-normal')

        if(preco):
            print(f'Produto: {titulo.text}')
            print(f'https://www.amazon.com.br/{url["href"]}')
            print(f'Preço: R${preco.text.replace(",", "")}')
        else:
            print(f'Produto não disponível: {titulo.text}...\nDa url: https://www.amazon.com.br/{url["href"]}')
        print("\n")

    continuar = False

print('\nLista acabada!')
```

Comment: é como dizem, os caras do stack overflow são anjos, obrigado por falar sobre a váriavel global, de todo o tempo q programo em python, essa é a primeira vez que uso váriavel global, muito obrigado

Comment: já dei upvote brow kk

Answer (score 1):

Achei uma solução eu mesmo, o código tá aqui pra quem quiser incorporar
https://github.com/farofaDeCachorro/myprojects/blob/main/amazon_automatic.py
licensa: cc0, pode usar a vontade

edit: quem quiser ajudar no código pode também rsrs

[image: um exemplo do código]